# ¿Como recorrer un arreglo de php en javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Estoy usando laravel para un proyecto, presento el siguiente problema, en el controlador tengo un array llamado escalafonvalor que se llena, luego ese array se lo envió a la vista usando return y compact, en la vista necesito pasar ese array a un script y recorrerlo dentro de javascript, el array de php lo paso al script de la siguiente manera en la vista blade:

```
<script>
var cont= "<?php echo $count;  ?>";
for (var index1 = 0; index1 < cont; index1++) {

        precioesca[index1]="<?php echo $escalafonvalor[".index1."] ?>";        


        alert(precioesca[index1]);

    }
</script>
```

el array llega de esta manera:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => 13282000
  1 => 4688000
  2 => 2344000
]
```

El array pasa correctamente al script, ya que si le doy indice 0 me muestra su valor y lo guarda en la variable js.
Mi problema viene es, al momento de intentar recorrer el array con la variable index1 del for de javascript , ya que me dice que la variable index1 es indefinida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que puede estar mal aquí? o ¿como debería hacerse ?

Comment: se hace con `cont.length` en el for

Comment: quieres decir entonces que el ciclo for lo haga de esta manera?..for (var index1 = 0; index1 < escalafonvalor.length ; index1++)

Comment: es necesario que la var cont este con `" "` deberias quitarlo para que te llegue el dato como tal.

Comment: ya edite la pregunta de como llega el array a la vista con un dd de laravel.  el array se llama escalafonvalor

Comment: bueno mira bien entonces , trata de quitarle los `" "` a la variable cont y prueba mi código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando la información que me dio Marcos la utilice de esta manera, les adjunto mi código por si le sirve a alguien.

```
var precioesca = [];
    var escalafon = "<?php echo json_encode($escalafonvalor); ?>";

    precioesca=JSON.parse(escalafon);


    for (var index = 0; index < precioesca.length; index++) {

        alert(precioesca[index]);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

En este caso la variable index1 es una variable en javascript, pero tu tratas de accesarla en php.  La forma correcta de hacerlo seria:

```
<script>
var precioesca = [];
var escalafon = <?php echo json_encode($escalafonvalor);  ?>;
var newEscalafon = JSON.parse(escalafon);

newEscalafon.forEach(function(value, index) {
    precioesca[index] = value;
    alert(precioesca[index]);
});
</script>
```

Comment: el php toca ponerlo entre comillas ?  por que al declararlo asi como tu dices  <?php $cont = 0; ?> se me pone el codigo azul de ahi para abajo y no lo toma

Comment: Intenta con comillas

Comment: solo me muestra la posicion cero (0) del arreglo no se aumenta

Comment: me parece logico tu codigo y tiene sentido, pero no se aumenta la variable cont del php, si toma el valor del cont pero volver el ciclo no aumenta siempre va a tomar el primer valor

@alanfcm

Comment: edite esta pregunta para que pruebes @ÁndresFelipePatiño

Comment: Tienes razon, la respuesta de Marcos es la correcta.  Ya edite mi respuesta con una pequeña modificacion que me parece que el omitio.

Answer (score 3):

Considera que el código `PHP` es compilado y ejecutado del lado del servidor, en cambio `JS` es compilado y ejecutado del lado del cliente (*normalmente un navegador*).

En otras palabras, **primero se ejecuta el código `PHP`, el resultado es devuelto al cliente y este ejecuta `JS`**.

Teniendo en cuenta esto, si necesitas recorrer en `JS` información almacenada en una variable de `PHP`, lo que tienes que hacer es **imprimir con `PHP` dicha información así se vuelve visible en `JS`**

### Solución:

Puedes usar la función [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php), la cual te permite convertir el valor de la variable a un objeto que `JS` puede procesar.

#### Ejemplo:

```
<script>
var precioesca = [];
var escalafon = <?php echo json_encode((array) $escalafonvalor);  ?>;

escalafon.forEach(function(value, index) {
    precioesca[index] = value;
    alert(precioesca[index]);
});
</script>
```

**PD:** La expresión `(array) $escalafonvalor` convertirá (*en el caso que no lo fuera*) `$escalafonvalor` en un arreglo, permitiendo así la correcta iteración con `JS`.

Comment: hola, con la función .foreach(function(value, index){
me generaba un error, lo probé de la siguiente manera:
for (var index = 0; index < escalafon.length; index++){

y lo imprimo con un alert y los ha guardado de esta manera:
[,1,3,2,8,2,0,0,0,,,4,6,8,8,0,0,0,,,2,3,4,4,0,0,0,]

eso es por el json? y como lo guardo normal? que traiga la posición 0=13282000
1=4688000
2=2344000

Comment: @ÁndresFelipePatiño, que tipo de dato tiene la variable ? Una forma de averiguarlo es haciendo `var_export($escalafonvalor)`. Así mismo, he actualizado mi respuesta.

Comment: hola marcos, gracias por tu ayuda, ya pude solucionarlo me sirvió mucho tu información

Comment: @ÁndresFelipePatiño, excelente noticia! Si la solución fue diferente, te recomiendo que crees una respuesta con el código. Si mi respuesta solucionó tu pregunta, considera votarla y/o marcarla como la mas acertada.

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera usando `length`, que hace que tome el total del largo del arreglo y se traduciría en for como `index < 10` por así decirlo como ejemplo.

```
<script>
var cont= "<?php echo $count;  ?>";
for (var index1 = 0; index1 < cont.length; index1++) {  
        alert(cont[index1]);

    }
</script>
```

Te dejo un ejemplo ejecutable para que lo veas en acción.

```js
 
    var cont = ["valor1",2,3,4,"valor3","texto",2,4];
    for (var index1 = 0; index1 < cont.length; index1++) {  
            console.log(cont[index1]);

    }
```

Comment: y como recorreria el arreglo '$escalafonvalor[]' que viene desde php?

Comment: muestra como te llega el arreglo en la pregunta en forma de texto , para ayudarte.

Comment: Lo que quiero es recorrer el array escalafonvalor[] de php 

el cual trae estos valores:
array:3 [▼
  0 => 13282000
  1 => 4688000
  2 => 2344000
]


@Sebastián

Comment: etonces que variables quieres recorrer count o escalafonvalor? , no será mejor enviar los dos al javascript tanto como count y escalafonvalor.no? o la variable count es escalafonvalor?

Comment: es que la variable count tiene un valor fijo y tambien la mando desde el controlador a la vista y en el script la capto y la guardo en la variable var cont, la cual uso para limitar el ciclo... y dentro del ciclo quiero recorrer el arreglo de php escalafonvalor[]

Comment: entonces envia la variable escalafonvalor a javascript igual pra recorrerla

Comment: Eso es lo que hago al usar  precioesca[contar]= "<?php echo $escalafonvalor[]; ?>";      pero no hay forma de recorrerlo de esa manera

Comment: y escalafonvalor como te llega? vamos a un chat mejor par esto @ÁndresFelipePatiño dejo chat espera.

Comment: sala de [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76573/javascript-recorrer-php)